# In SAPUI5 can I disable fullscreen mode for sap.m.Input suggestions on mobile?

Tags: sapui5

Is there a way to prevent a `sap.m.Input` with `showSuggestion` set to true from going into fullscreen mode when a mobile user focuses on it and enters text in it?

Here's a screenshot of what I'm talking about:

[image: screenshot of input and suggestions taking up entire screen with a Close button at the bottom]

For my use case, 95% of the time users won't see a suggestion so having it enter fullscreen mode is very disruptive and confusing.

Comment: I don't get it.. Why enable `showSuggestions` if "users won't see a suggestion".. what?

Comment: I have a mobile app which supports multiple users on the same device i.e. a company iPad. I want to fill the input suggestions with the email addresses of users who have logged in to the app before so returning users don't need to type out their full email address; in most cases this will be only 2 - 5 people. So if you're using the app for the first time, you probably won't see a single suggestion while you're entering your email address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/input-field/

> Size S (Smartphones)
>   Cozy mode:
>   When the user clicks or taps the input field, a new full screen dialog opens in which suggested items can be selected. Here, the pop-in feature of the responsive table is used.

No, that's how the input control works on mobile.